# Is there an Azure command line interface for these AWS CLI functions

Tags: powershell, azure, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have an application which uses the Aamzon command line interface to describe, start, stop and reboot instances. I want to build a version on Azure. Does anyone know if there is a CLI like interface for Azure for the following please?

```
ec2-describe-instances

ec2-reboot-instances

ec2-start-instances

ec2-stop-instances
```

Comment: See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495240.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the azure powershell or the azure xcli

on the azure [xcli](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) these commands are

```
azure vm show
azure vm restart
azure vm start
azure vm stop
```

To the the list you can use

```
azure vm list
```

On the [Powershell](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/) the commands are

```
Get-AzureVM
Restart-AzureVM
Start-AzureVM
Stop-AzureVM
```